# Splitting a merge into batches in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I am trying to find the best way to perform a SQL Server `merge` in batches.
`TEMPTABLENAME` is a temp table with an id column (and all the other columns).

I am thinking some kind of while loop using the id as a counter.

The real problem with the merge statement is that it locks the entire table for an extended amount of time when processing 200K+ records. I want to loop every 100 rows so I can release the lock and let the other applications access the table. This table has millions of rows and also fires off an audit every time data is updated. This causes 160K records to take around 20 to 30 mins in the merge below.

The merge code below is a sample of the code. There is probably about 25 columns that get updated/inserted.

I would be open to finding another way other than the merge to insert the data. I just can not change the audit system or amount of records in the table.

```
merge Employee as Target
using TEMPTABLENAME as Source on (Target.ClientId = Source.ClientId and 
                                  Target.EmployeeReferenceId = Source.EmployeeReferenceId)

when matched then
    update 
    set 
       Target.FirstName = Source.FirstName,
       Target.MiddleName = Source.MiddleName,
       Target.LastName = Source.LastName,
       Target.BirthDate = Source.BirthDate

when not matched then

    INSERT ([FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [BirthDate])
    VALUES (Source.FirstName, Source.MiddleName, Source.LastName, Source.BirthDate)

OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;

SELECT Change, COUNT(*) AS CountPerChange
FROM @SummaryOfChanges
GROUP BY Change;
```

Comment: Aren't you worried about transactional integrity though?

Comment: Have you tried any of these: [Optimizing MERGE Statement Performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: To a point yes, but the records that are getting updated "should" not get updated by another application. We can say the group of records getting updated belong to a client. While records under other clients may get updated at the same time this clients records should not really get updated from another application. I would really like to keep the merge and batch it in 100's. This way the 100 records getting updated would still be transactional and any updates before or after would be acceptable.